# Как получить все данные с словаря, в который вложенные другие словари?

Tags: python

Есть такой, к примеру, словарь

```
{'Peter_III': {'Anna': {'Peter_I': {'None': 'None'}}}}
```

Как сделать из него массив, в котором будут все значения с этого словаря:

```
['Peter_III', 'Anna', 'Peter_I', 'None', 'None']
```

`dict.items`, `keys` или `values` не решают это.

Comment: Можете прикрепить пример делаемого результата?

Comment: ['Peter_III','Anna','Peter_I','None', 'None']

Comment: Если вам помог один из ответов, отметьте его галочкой, если нет, задайте дополнительные вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Можно рекурсивно обойти все словари:

```
import collections

def iterate_mapping(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield k
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            yield from iterate_mapping(v)
        else:
            yield v
```

Использование:

```
>>> list(iterate_mapping({'Peter_III': {'Anna': {'Peter_I': {'None': 'None'}}}}))
['Peter_III', 'Anna', 'Peter_I', 'None', 'None']
```

Comment: Надо-же. Нестандартное решение)

Comment: @Alban, как раз вполне нормальное решение, в отличие от перевода в словаря в текст, и последующего разбора текста регуляркой.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
>>> dct = {'Peter_III': {'Anna': {'Peter_I': {'None': 'None'}}}}
>>> result = re.findall(pattern, str(dct))
>>> result
['Peter_III', 'Anna', 'Peter_I', 'None', 'None']
```

Comment: Не сработает, если в значениях будут пробелы или знаки препинания. Вообще, довольно неоптимальное решение.

Comment: @insolor признаю регулярка тут не очень удачный выбор